# Issue with feature type overriding after ingest values to FeatureSet

Tags: python, feature-store, mlrun

I see that some feature types were changed after ingest value to the feature set, see information in log:

```
> 2023-07-08 17:29:42,018 [warning] Overriding type of entity 'fn0' from 'int' to 'int32'. This may result in errors or unusable data.
> 2023-07-08 17:29:42,018 [warning] Overriding type of entity 'fn1' from 'int' to 'int32'. This may result in errors or unusable data.
> 2023-07-08 17:29:42,018 [warning] Overriding type of entity 'fn2' from 'int' to 'int32'. This may result in errors or unusable data.
> 2023-07-08 17:29:46,792 [warning] Overriding type of entity 'fn0' from 'int32' to 'int'. This may result in errors or unusable data.
> 2023-07-08 17:29:46,792 [warning] Overriding type of entity 'fn1' from 'int32' to 'int'. This may result in errors or unusable data.
> 2023-07-08 17:29:46,792 [warning] Overriding type of entity 'fn2' from 'int32' to 'int'. This may result in errors or unusable data.
```

I used this sample code

```
feature_set = fstore.FeatureSet(feature_name, entities=[fstore.Entity("fn0"),
                                                            fstore.Entity("fn1"),
                                                            fstore.Entity("fn2")],
                                engine="storey")        
feature_set.set_targets(targets=[RedisNoSqlTarget(path="redis://redis-fs-test.eu.infra:6379")],
                        with_defaults=False)
feature_set.save()
...
fstore.ingest(feature_set,dataFrm,overwrite=False)
```

Do you know, how can I avoid type overriding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. You have to do two steps:

1. You have to **define all entities and features** with relevant types during FeatureSet definition
2. Than, you can use ingest with setting **`infer_options=data_types.InferOptions.Null`** (based on that, you switch-off type discovery and type overriding)

See new code:

```
feature_set = fstore.FeatureSet(feature_name, entities=[fstore.Entity("fn0", value_type=data_types.ValueType.INT32),
                                                        fstore.Entity("fn1", value_type=data_types.ValueType.INT32),
                                                        fstore.Entity("fn2", value_type=data_types.ValueType.INT32)],
                                engine="storey")
feature_set.add_feature(mlrun.feature_store.Feature(data_types.ValueType.INT32,name="fn3"))
feature_set.add_feature(mlrun.feature_store.Feature(data_types.ValueType.INT32,name="fn4"))
...

feature_set.set_targets(targets=[RedisNoSqlTarget(path="redis://redis-fs-test.eu.infra:6379")],
                        with_defaults=False)
feature_set.save()
...
fstore.ingest(feature_set,dataFrm,overwrite=False, infer_options=data_types.InferOptions.Null)
```